# Visual Studio changing the way Ctrl-K-D works

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, visual-studio, formatting

In Visual Studio (I'm using 2012), is there any way of editing the way that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> combinations handles its **Auto-Formatting**?

I don't mean changing what these key combinations do, I mean *extending the way the auto-formatting is done*.

The way it handles *tabbing*, etc are fine, I'm more concerned with **white-space**.

We're using a plugin that makes it easy to align variable properties, making them easy to read.  Like so:

```
var test            = 'whatever',
    another         = 'this one',
    alignedProperly = 'yay';
```

Seems nitt-picky yes, but in really large Object literals it's so helpful to be able to read them!

**Has anyone found where the rules for auto-formatting are located, and if they can be edited/changed?** (Can't find them anywhere in the options!)

Comment: On my laptop it is Ctrl+E+D, in my office Ctrl+K+D! And the strange side of this, the versions are identical. So I think it is related to windows' settings.

Comment: @ozkanozlu When you first start Visual Studio after installation, you can choose which shortcut keys profile you want. For example, one is Visual Basic, another is C++, another is C#. Maybe two different profiles were chosen.

Comment: for me both `Ctrl + E + D` and `Ctrl + K + D` work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you looking for:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Spacing > Set other
>   spacing options > Ignore space in declaration statements

This is in VS 2010, but i guess 2012 should be somewhat similar.

Comment: Good catch! Wow that will definitely be a nice addition to our C# code as well! Just was looking under `Formatting > Spacing` (for Javascript), and of course this isn't an option :/ Silly JS haha

Comment: visit the link https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0cc34d69-c6f1-41e3-ac6e-5de071b3edc8

Answer (score 6):

In VS 2017:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Spacing > Set other spacing options > Ignore space in declaration statements

Comment: ill have to try this didn't know something new was in. 2017 for this! 

Answer (score 2):

This functionality has been changed to Ctrl+K, Ctrl+E.
This is called Code Cleanup.
Click on the "duster" on the bottom of VS page and click "Configure Code Cleanup" to assign specific actions.

[Code Cleanup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAAi7.png)