# How to automatically delete tabs in Razor syntax in MVC4 projects by pressing Ctrk + K + D?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When I press `Ctrl+K+D` in an MVC4 project in Visual Studio 2013 it makes some tabs (depends of tabs option) from the left border.

I use Razor syntax in my `Views`. But I do not nee tab indentation in Razor syntax (its suppose to be zero) by pressing `Ctrl+K+D`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was previously answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281099/visual-studio-changing-the-way-ctrl-k-d-works)

As stated in [publicgk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219516/publicgk) answer:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Spacing > Set other
>   spacing options > Ignore space in declaration statements

Also, if you want you can set the editor to use space characters and not tabs.

Comment: I do not need tabs only in Razor syntax. For example, when I pressing Ctrl + K + D I want to see my code like this - http://screencast.com/t/ZYhmNxERtE but it automatically add few tabs - http://screencast.com/t/HjVSHXuRGN